# What's wrong with brainfuck on ideone?

Tags: brainfuck

Clearly, there is something wrong with my understanding of brainfuck, or there's something wrong with bf interpreter on ideone.com.

By entering code as simple as `,.,.` (reads two characters and prints them), I get an error "bff: out of memory (871638280)" . Why do I get this ?

NOTE: The true problem is that I'm trying to solve a problem on SPOJ, and some code that works on brainfuck interpreters that I found across the internet, doesn't work on SPOJ and ideone.com.

Comment: Have you tried it on any other interpreter? It's the absolute minimum you could have done to actually try answering your own question. And that would have been enough

Comment: if that's the case, then it's probably their interpreter which is buggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to work fine, my BF torture test runs properly.

ideone.com 9fQ2Ej

I am NOT going to try to fight this UI to make the BF look correct!
It's here:
    https://github.com/rdebath/Brainfuck/blob/master/bitwidth.b

It does appear to have a large cells size though and isn't fast enough to offset this.

EDIT: (No newlines below Grrr)

Anyway Daniel Christofani's end test:

> ,>+++++++++,>+++++++++++[<++++++<++++++<+>>>-]<<.>.<<-.>.>.<<.

Gives 'LA' showing that the program accepts input successfully, gives the correct character for newline and gives '-1' for end of file. As it's a big cell interpreter this is perfectly acceptable.

HOWEVER; I do see your point, there's something weird going on I suggest you try one of the javaScript implementations. They run in your browser.

http://t-monster.com/apps/brainfuck_IDE

http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf_online.html

http://brainfuck.devbar.de/

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
but you don't have any comas in your code, thats you don't have any input, and I have a problem when I try to proccess the input :)